# MYSQL Skip the fetching of a column after query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to run queries in mysql and dislay the output in some way, however the queries are provided by a third party and I can't change them. An example would be:

```
SELECT j.`First Name`, j.`Last Name`, c .*
 FROM PersonalInfo j
    INNER JOIN
      Evaluations c
      ON j.UIN = c.UIN
```

Where table PersonalInfo has people's personal info and table Evaluations stores people's evaluations. The Evaluations table contains blob fields where the (sometimes heavy) pdf's of the evaluations have been stored.

The problem with this query is that since Evaluations have blob fields and these are selected in the SELECT statement I have no option than to read those fields when I do $result->fetch_assoc() as below

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($DTIS->query)){
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // at this point I believe the (heavy) blob info has been fetched and put into $row["blobfield"] right ?
    // if field is blob display just a link, otherwise the info.
   }
}
```

Is there a way to SKIP THE FETCHING of a specific COLUMN so I can display the table quickly without reading any of the heavy blob info ? Remember I can't change the query string. Any code template is also appreciated it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, you can and should always specify only the columns you actually need instead of all of it `c.*`!

Comment: Why can't you edit the query before using it in mysqli->query()?

Comment: Not to mention you're coding it but cant select the columns you need only? That is by itself wrong.

Comment: Coming up with a script that would interpret the query and modifies it on the fly to avoid selecting given columns is not trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below way to access your data field wise, however it is some what lengthy but may be useful to you:

1. First find the number of rows for that query // which you can get using mysql_num_rows
2. Loop using that number in below way, to get only selected field data one by one

   ```
   $result = mysql_query($query); 
   $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
   $i = 0;
   while ($i < $count) { 

      $firstColumnData[]  = mysql_result($result, $i, 'first_field_name');
      $secondColumnData[] = mysql_result($result, $i, 'second_field_name');
      $i++;
   }
   ```

In this way, you may get only desired field data from mysql result set.

Comment: Thanks. This is a solution to my problem, though I understand  the procedural method of using mysql_result will be deprecated in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If queries are provided by a third party and you can't change them - no.